# Is it possible to use xsd:redefine to extend, not restrict?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML Schema (XSD) which I want to use to validate XML data, but one very specific thing about the XML data is not compliant.  I want to generate an alternate XSD to use to successfully validate the XML.  More specifically, I want to *extend* the definition of a type to allow a value not allowed by the original XSD.  It is not practical to modify the original XSD.

Here's the original definition from the original XSD:

```
<simpleType name="fooType">
  <restriction base="token">
    <pattern value="[a-z]+"/>
    <enumeration value="foo"/>
  </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

I want to allow the value "123" too for the entity which uses this type definition.  So, I tried this:

```
<redefine schemaLocation="original.xsd">
  <simpleType name="fooType">
    <extension base="orig:fooType">
      <enumeration value="123"/>
    </extension>
  </simpleType>
</redefine>
```

I admit I'm just winging it, I don't know XSD.  But before I read the standard, I want to know if this is even possible?  All (and I mean *all*) examples I could find of xsd:redefine have been to *restrict* the possible values, not *extend* them.

And if not using xsd:redefine, then how can I do this?

**Edit:** Related, but uninformative: [Extending XSD files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976656/extending-xsd-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of a simpleType can only be a restriction, list or union. Since when redefining a type you have to reference as a base type the one you're redefining, you are then stuck; restriction is the only one you can have.

For completeness, there is one technique to allow for open enumerations, that involves the use of union content, but, since you cannot touch the original schema, it won't work in your case.

One more observation: Having a pattern and an enumeration, is kind of "useless"; in your case the only value you can have is "foo".